Configure Setup Wizard to not install Google TV Launcher
I'm configuring Android TV 11 for a tv box. There I use the standard setup wizard (com.google.android.tungsten.setupwraith, the recent version) and "Android TV Home launcher". The setup wizard runs with the first run of the device to configure the system and I have a problem with it. During the configuration process it checks if there is "Google TV Home" launcher in the system and installs it if it is not there. Then, when the configuration is finished it runs the Google TV Launcher. How can I configure the setup wizard to not download the google launcher?

You could try to extract the setup wizard and decompile it using Jadx-Gui to see if there is a possibility to disable/bypass Google TV Home installation. May be a dummy app with the same packageName can do the trick if there is no option to bypass installation?
